# How can user change location on mapkit iphone dev?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an app in which i need to use map kit(first time) and i am also new in iphone. My requirement is that user can edit location and set his desired location using pin. I follow many tutorial but i couldn't get this that users can change location to move pin on map. Any help plz, thnx.

Comment: Did you mean pin drops where the user taps the map?

Comment: yes, like user last location set on north side(some location) of NY and if user click on east side(some location) NY then it'll change location to east side of NY, using pin, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a UIGestureRecognizer to detect touches on the map view.

In the place where you setup the map view (in viewDidLoad for example), attach the gesture recognizer to the map view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tgr = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
tgr.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
tgr.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:tgr];
[tgr release];
```

or to use a long press:

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *lpgr = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] 
initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0;  //user must press for 2 seconds
[mapView addGestureRecognizer:lpgr];
[lpgr release];
```

In the handleGesture: method:

```
- (void)handleGesture:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{
    if (gestureRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    return;

    CGPoint touchPoint = [gestureRecognizer locationInView:mapView];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D touchMapCoordinate = 
    [mapView convertPoint:touchPoint toCoordinateFromView:mapView];

    MKPointAnnotation *pa = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
    pa.coordinate = touchMapCoordinate;
    pa.title = @"Hello";
    [mapView addAnnotation:pa];
    [pa release];
}
```